# Midnight Commander: user running commands or scripts/executables

Tags: linux, putty, midnight-commander

When I putty to my CentOS (6.4) and launch mc as a normal user (not root) I get fired from the putty window: Server unexpectedly closed network connection. This quit annoying if you are used to execute programs and run commands from the command line in mc. I get this whenever I try to execute anything by enter/double clik or try to call a program from the command line. When I run the program to be executed with sudo it opens it nicely, but I like the enter/click method and would not like to type allways the file name.

Here is my /etc/mc folder:

```
drwxr-xr-x. 121 root root 12288 Nov 14 10:59 ..
-rw-r--r--.   1 root root 12278 Aug 22  2010 cedit.menu
-rw-r--r--.   1 root root   788 Aug 22  2010 edit.indent.rc
-rw-r--r--.   1 root root   247 Aug 22  2010 edit.spell.rc
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root  4096 Oct 15 10:50 extfs
-rw-r--r--.   1 root root  1024 Aug 22  2010 filehighlight.ini
-rw-r--r--.   1 root root   226 Aug 22  2010 mc.charsets
-rw-r--r--.   1 root root 17353 Aug 22  2010 mc.ext
-rw-r--r--.   1 root root  7936 Aug 22  2010 mc.keymap
-rw-r--r--.   1 root root  7936 Aug 22  2010 mc.keymap.default
-rw-r--r--.   1 root root  7913 Aug 22  2010 mc.keymap.emacs
-rw-r--r--.   1 root root  1979 Aug 22  2010 mc.lib
-rw-r--r--.   1 root root  9556 Aug 22  2010 mc.menu
-rw-r--r--.   1 root root 10126 Aug 22  2010 mc.menu.sr
-rw-r--r--.   1 root root  6259 Aug 22  2010 Syntax
```

The mc from /user/bin

```
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root       988432 Aug 22  2010 mc
```

For example, here is a file I would like to execute through mc with normal user:

```
-rwxrwxr-x  1 root hUSERS  205780 Jun 11 16:03 DBU3L
```

I saw in a forum a program called sam that maybe could be used, but would not like to reinvent the wheel if this could be fixed by changing some rights or mc parameters.

These are the putty log's last lines:

```
[44m*DBU3L[23;3H[1;1H[39m[49m[K
[K
[K
[K
[K
[K
[K
[K
[K
[K
[K
[K
[K
[K
[K
[K
[K
[K
[K
[K
[K
[K
[K
[K[1;80H[?1002l[?1001r[?1l>[24;1H(B[m[39;49m
[K
[?1049l>[?47l8[m$ ./DBU3L
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had a custom login shell script, not /bin/bash that is called when executing a program from mc.

So simply in that login shell script I added a check to see if the login shell was called from mc:

```
mc=`ps $PPID | grep mc`
if [ ! -z "$mc" -a "$mc"!=" " ]
then
        clear
        cmd="$1 $2 $3 $4 $5"
        cmd=`echo $cmd | cut -c 4-`
        bash -c "$cmd"
        exit
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try logging your session, maybe it'll show why it's crashing. Did you try another `ssh` client?

[image]

Comment: added what the log returns, I don't use other ssh clients, I think this is reliable and most used by, what would be you recommandation and why?